# How to control links and navigation in a website using arrow keys (without using flash)?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

In this [website](http://www.area17.com/work/vice-motherboard-website), an anchor link (right blue arrow) is activated with the `right arrow key`. I'm not sure if a new page is loaded when that anchor link is activated.

How can I accomplish that effect?

The page also goes to the top when the `up (upper?) arrow key` is pressed. How can I accomplish that too?

Answer (score 1):

It's all done through javascript.  I didn't look too far into the pages javascript files but the basic concept is to use the javascript [onkeypress event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp) to call a [change to the current url](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_assign.asp).  This can also be done with jquery [.keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) if you want to use that instead.  The same idea goes for the up arrow key function which would possibly just press the page up key for you which can be done with the sendkeys method.